# Scotsman Ice Machine DCE33 will not eject ice

Tags: kitchens, appliances, ice-maker

The Scotsman Automatic Ice Machine DCE33 continues to run water and the ice cubes don't eject? Help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your model has a harvest timer.  After a set freeze time, the timer should operate a hot gas reversing valve that will slightly warm the freeze surface and cause the cubes to eject by gravity.  The timer or coil on the hot gas valve can fail.  The harvest cycle will also drain water that wasn't used in the last cycle and refill.  It seems like waste but this is how Scotsman makes clear and not cloudy cubes, the water ejected will contain the minerals that didn't make it into the ice.

First thing to check tho, is whether ice is forming.  The cubes are made by spraying water into a form that's closed on top, open on the bottom.  (Like an upside down ice tray.) Water that doesn't freeze falls back down into a sump, where it is pumped and sprayed again continuously.  Shut the unit off and stick ur fingers upward behind the plastic curtain where the ice comes out, do you feel ice in the forms? Or empty ice forms?

Those Scotsmen models operate more efficiently when the bin has ice it, than completely empty.  The storage box is not refrigerated, just insulated.  Residual cold from ice already made helps.  Also a bad seal on the door gasket can significantly reduce ice production by letting heat in/cold out.

Have you cleaned the condenser coil?  A dirty coil can keep it from producing ice.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We replaced the timer and ice cube thermostat. Now we have ice again. Checking the condenser coils is a must.